# Where is the Postgres username/password being created in this Dockerfile?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I was following this tutorial:
https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/

I have everything up and running, but there are a few things going on that I'm not able to follow or understand.

In the main Docker-Compose we have:

```
web:
  restart: always
  build: ./web
  expose:
    - "8000"
  links:
    - postgres:postgres
    - redis:redis
  volumes:
    - /usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/static
  env_file: .env
  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

postgres:
  restart: always
  image: postgres:latest
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
```

You will notice there is a env_file containing:

```
DB_NAME=postgres    
DB_USER=postgres    
DB_PASS=postgres
```

My question is when is the postgres user and password being set?  If I run this docker-compose everything works, meaning the web app can pass credentials to the postgres database and establish a connection.  I'm not able to follow however, where those credentials are being set in the first place.

I was assuming in the base postgres Dockerfile, there would be some instruction to set the database name, username and password. Here is a copy of the base postgres Dockerfile below.

```
# vim:set ft=dockerfile:

FROM debian:jessie



# explicitly set user/group IDs

RUN groupadd -r postgres --gid=999 && useradd -r -g postgres --uid=999 postgres



# grab gosu for easy step-down from root

ENV GOSU_VERSION 1.7

RUN set -x \

    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ca-certificates wget && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \

    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture)" \

    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-$(dpkg --print-architecture).asc" \

    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \

    && gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \

    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \

    && rm -r "$GNUPGHOME" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \

    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \

    && gosu nobody true \

    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove ca-certificates wget



# make the "en_US.UTF-8" locale so postgres will be utf-8 enabled by default

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \

    && localedef -i en_US -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias en_US.UTF-8

ENV LANG en_US.utf8



RUN mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d



RUN apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys B97B0AFCAA1A47F044F244A07FCC7D46ACCC4CF8



ENV PG_MAJOR 9.6

ENV PG_VERSION 9.6.1-1.pgdg80+1



RUN echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ jessie-pgdg main' $PG_MAJOR > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list



RUN apt-get update \

    && apt-get install -y postgresql-common \

    && sed -ri 's/#(create_main_cluster) .*$/\1 = false/' /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf \

    && apt-get install -y \

        postgresql-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \

        postgresql-contrib-$PG_MAJOR=$PG_VERSION \

    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*



# make the sample config easier to munge (and "correct by default")

RUN mv -v /usr/share/postgresql/$PG_MAJOR/postgresql.conf.sample /usr/share/postgresql/ \

    && ln -sv ../postgresql.conf.sample /usr/share/postgresql/$PG_MAJOR/ \

    && sed -ri "s!^#?(listen_addresses)\s*=\s*\S+.*!\1 = '*'!" /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample



RUN mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql && chown -R postgres /var/run/postgresql



ENV PATH /usr/lib/postgresql/$PG_MAJOR/bin:$PATH

ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data

VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data



COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /



ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]



EXPOSE 5432

CMD ["postgres"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the postgres user and password is being set on entrypoint, like in line 23 on official image entrypoint.

https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/e4942cb0f79b61024963dc0ac196375b26fa60dd/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh

Can you check your entrypoint?

Comment: I am using the official postgres image so I believe you have answered my question.  So in this docker-entrypoint.sh, what is the username and password being set?  I am asking because I am not good at reading bash script.

Answer (score 44):

Not sure which postgres image are you using.

If you look at the [official postgres image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) for complete information. It allows user to specify the **environment variables** for the below ones and these can be easily overridden at run time.

- POSTGRES_PASSWORD
- POSTGRES_USER
- PGDATA
- POSTGRES_DB
- POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS

Environment variables can be overridden using below three methods depending on your case.

- **Run Image:** If **running docker image** directly, use below to include environment variable in `docker run` with `-e K=V`. Please refer documentation for more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secrect -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres <other options> image/name
```

- **Dockerfile:** If you need to specify the environment variable in `Dockerfile`, specify as mentioned below. Please refer documentation for more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)

```
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secrect
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

- **docker-compose:** If you need to specify the environment variable in `docker-compose.yml`, specify as below. Please refer documentation for more details [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/)

```
web:
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secrect
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: My question is where in my example are credentials being set.  I have an env file but these are environment variables for my Django project to connect to postgres with.

Comment: Is service `web` requires to connect? then define there as shown in the `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: It is already defined somewhere, as when I run docker compose, it fires up a web app and django is connecting to the db.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456 postgres
```

In the same way you can set up the username like below:

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_USERNAME=xyz postgres
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the -v mounted folder? If so, you need to remove the entire pgdata/ folder you created previously so that the postgres can re-create itself using the new environment variables.

Comment: My godness you! U save my 2 hours. Thank you so much